# Add view more button

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have this section created by bootstrap SQLserver and php...

Is there any way to display just a little of it and give the view more button option to display the whole result?

[image]

There are like 10 Decks, and I want e.g to sidplay just 2 and when user clicks View More to display all of them.

This is my php code for that result.

```
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<count($decks);$i++){
   $deck_name = $decks[$i]['name'];
   $deck_desc = $decks[$i]['description'];                                        
   $deck_img_link = $json['deckplans'][$i]['images'][0]['href'];
  echo "<img class='bd-imagelink-157 bd-own-margins bd-imagestyles' src='$deck_img_link'><p class='bd-textblock-779 bd-content-element'>$deck_name</p>";
   echo $deck_desc;
 }
?>
</div>
```

I tried to put the bootstrap add more button but is displayed in the end of the section,after all content is loaded, and is pointless

Comment: Why are you using a for loop and not a foreach loop? Your loop start could easily be defined as `foreach($decks as $deck)` and then you can call for example `$deck_name` would be `$deck['name']`.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically request and load in more content per deck or just reveal all decks on the front end when `View More` is clicked?

Comment: @SebCooper i really dont mind.. I cant manage either. Just want to make it work.. But probably requesting is more difficult with ajax and I have no clue of ajax, just a little bit on JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how you might reveal additional hidden items one at a time. You will need to use the jQuery JavaScript library for this to work.

```js
$('#viewmore').on('click', function(){
 $('.item:hidden').show();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
ITEM 1
</div>
<div class="item hidden">
ITEM 2
</div>
<div class="item hidden">
ITEM 3
</div>
<div class="item hidden">
ITEM 4
</div>
<button id="viewmore">
View More
</button>
</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show all items when click view more instead of showing one by one?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `.first()` method from the event handler selector. [Updated the answer to reflect this.]